# Первый сайт на php

Tags: php, html, ide

В какой программе и как начать изучение php? То есть мне нужен толчок, чтоб я написал первую программу на данном языке.

Answer (score 5):

Ну для начала вам нужен сервер на котором ваши php скрипты будут работать, для этих целей пойдёт Denwer. Скрипты можно писать хоть в блокноте, но всё же такие редакторы как NotePad++ предоставляют более удобный интерфейс. А дальше читаем книги посещаем http://php.su и т.д..

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - ставьте себе денвер или Xampp. Потом, например, ZendStudio или NuSphere PhpED. И вперед. Блокнотом пользоваться новичку не сильно приятно, а в этих прогах идет автоматическая проверка синтаксиса и много-много других прибамбасов. Для работы с базами данных рекомендую SQL Manager Lite for MySQL: в ней все просто и понятно.
И как всегда начните со стандартной первой программой на php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам подойдет любой текстовой редактор с подсветкой кода, например notepad++. Из вопроса не совсем понятно, что вы знаете о php (что-то подсказываете, что вы о нем только слышали и даже еще ничего не читали), как только начнете ознакомление я думаю и с редактором проще будет определиться, ведь дело не в текстовом редакторе и среде разработки.

В другом ответе товарищ RooTooZ уже оставлял сылочку http://www.phpfaq.ru/na_tanke , можно начать с этого и не останавливаясь продолжить какой-нибуть книгой для начинающих.

Answer (score 0):

Makromedia DreamWiewer, Apache, MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Самым легким вариантом будет.

1. Как веб-сервер использовать Denwer т.к у него минимум настроек.
2. Кому как удобней,  лично я использовал и использую текстовый редактор NotePad++ (NotePad2 тоже удобный).подсветка синтаксиса и т.д. Вообщем очень удобно.
    3.Рано или поздно придеться где то хранить данные которые будет использывать ваша программа. Mysql  для этого самое оно.Качаем сервер Mysql с офф сайта. С консольным вариантом управления БД управлять не очень удобно. Рекомендую поставить NaviCat, быстро и удобно)

Comment: А я когда изучал PHP, работал с MySQL, и по ходу освоения того и другого писал на PHP и HTML интерфейс для работы с MySQL (создание БД, таблиц, записей, запросы, вывод)... Даже где то вроде осталось всё)

Answer (score 0):

думаю для вас это тоже будет интересно ,

у вас к концу дня уже будет сайт на пхп  который вы сами сделали своими руками.

вот эта ссылка http://www.php-adminka.ru/